# programmatically access macbook pro camera java

Tags: java, macos, camera

How can I access the camera on my macbook pro to use as input to a java program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use the QTKit library to do that. Check this guide out (for Objective-C applications, but Java can access the system APIs as well through different bindings, so you should be able to apply the same in Java).

- [QTKit Application Tutorial](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/QTKitApplicationTutorial/BuildingaSimpleQTKitCaptureApplication/BuildingaSimpleQTKitCaptureApplication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008155-CH8-SW1)
- [Accessing Cocoa From Java](http://finbarrbrady.com/2010/03/accessing-cocoa-frameworks-from-java/)