# Using VLCJ to capture video from camera on mac osx

Tags: java, macos, webcam, video-capture, vlcj

Does anyone know how to specify the MRL for the default camera on mac osx (lion) in the call to mediaPlayerComponent.getMediaPlayer().playMedia(mrl)? For example I can do it under Windows and Linux using MRLs like dshow:// and v4l2:///dev/video0 as indicated in the CaptureTest sample at

http://code.google.com/p/vlcj/source/browse/trunk/vlcj/src/test/java/uk/co/caprica/vlcj/test/capture/CaptureTest.java

But there is no information on using this on osx. I am fairly new to this area of video capture, so please excuse me if I am not framing the question properly.

The answer post at [Get webcam stream on Mac Os X in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750568/get-webcam-stream-on-mac-os-x-in-java) seems to indicate that it is possible. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Well, we will have to wait for the coming VLC 1.2.0, 2.0.0 and 2.1.0 for MacOSX and iOS support. Right now, they haven't revealed yet the MRL moniker for the video capture device under MacOSX and iOS (I wonder if Apple user will ever use VLC command line feature...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For OSX lion use:

String[] options= {"encoding etc"};
mediaPlayer.playMedia("qtcapture://", options)

Link to where I found it:
http://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=89140&p=312840&hilit=qtcapture%3A%2F%2F#p312840

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks! I moved on to using OpenCVFrameGrabber in a loop but I will investigate vlcj now too.